# Swift: Make SKPayment with only the product Id

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to instantiate an SKPayment object

```
let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
```

All I know is the productID

```
var productID = "MyId"
```

[Apples documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/fetching_product_information_from_the_app_store) mentions some delegate methods for accessing the product, `productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProd` but the problem is that their delegate methods, so I can't call them and don't know how to use them to get my products

---

If you want to view the bigger project instead of just whats on this question, the project is on [this github](https://github.com/stackoverflowsam93/iap)

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/5456-in-app-purchase-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: @Paulw11 I already went through that, I'm trying to create a simpler example. Plus that tutorial does not mention how to do what my question asks.

Comment: Ok, but your question isn’t clear. As I said on the last question that you deleted, you can’t create an SKProduct. That tutorial shows how to retrieve products using a `SKProductsRequest`. Once you have the `SKProduct` instance you can purchase it.

Comment: @Paulw11 Sorry I had to delete it because the question it was marked as duplicate for couldn't be deleted unless the duplicate question was deleted first.

Comment: It would probably have been better to simply edit your first question to clarify rather than asking new questions

Comment: @Paulw11 The program I'm writing is actually an adaptation of the program in that tutorial with some things changed and taken out, I'm at a point now where I only have the productidentifier and I"m trying to make a purchase using it but according to you I can't so It looks like I need to back up more and put more stuff back in

Comment: Yes. The short answer to your question is “you can’t”.

Comment: @Paulw11 Originally I wanted both questions, to me they weren't duplicates. I tried to edit the old question to be the new question but I couldn't because a question already existed with the same title(My new question). I realize now that I could have deleted my new question and then edited my old question to be my new question, but it didn't occur to me at the time. This is what I have now.

Comment: @Paulw11 I don't know how to modify the code from that example to do payments when not using a uitableview. The tutorial doesn't explain the part which I am concerned about. They attach a buttonHandler to the tableview cell `    cell.buyButtonHandler = { product in
      RazeFaceProducts.store.buyProduct(product)
    }` but I don't know how to attach an action that does the same thing to my button

Comment: Do you know how to attach an action to a button?  Use `@IBAction` if you are using storyboards, `addTarget` if not.  Then in that function you can execute the purchase.  You will need to have stored the `SKProduct` in a property where you can get it.

Comment: @Paulw11 I figured it out. So the request was already being made within my main view controller like this `RazeFaceProducts.store.requestProducts{ [weak self] success, products in
      guard let self = self else { return }
      if success {
        self.products = products!
      }
      }
  }`

I then had to loop through my products and check all of them to see if one matched
`for prod in self.products{
      if prod.productIdentifier == RazeFaceProducts.SwiftShopping{`

I wasn't thinking about that last step

Comment: this github repo might help you understand IAP better: https://github.com/BooberBunz/In-app-purchases-on-IOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you have is the productID then you must make a request to app store connect in order to obtain the product objects.

```
let productIdentifiers: Set<ProductIdentifier> = ["myId"]
let store = IAPHelper(productIds: productIdentifiers)
var products = [SKProduct]

store.requestProducts{ [weak self] success, products in
        guard let self = self 
        else { return }
        if success {
            self.products = products!
        }
    }
}
```

Once you have the products you can loop through them and see if any of their identifiers match the productID of interest. If one does, you can use that product.

```
for prod in self.products{
    if prod.productIdentifier == "myId"{
        let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "You can't".

You need to issue an `SKProductsRequest` through StoreKit in order to retrieve the `SKProduct` instances from the App Store.  Once you have retrieved the product instances you can use them to display an appropriate user interface and allow purchasing.

When the user initiates the purchase operation you can pass the `SKProduct` that was retrieved.